# TextView is onfocus stealing onclick event?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, textview, android

when I set a click listener for my TextView the initial click does not fire the event. here is the textview:

```
<TextView 
  style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
  android:id="@+id/my_text_area"
  android:layout_width="0dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:padding="10dip"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  ></TextView>

// OnCreate:
TextView link = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_area);
// "this" is my Activity that implements OnClickListener
link.setOnClickListener(this); 

void OnClick(view v) {
    //only gets fired after the first time
}
```

When I click the textview the following happens:

click 1. the textview recieves focus
click 2. OnClick is fired

I need click 1 to fire it as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close ...

```
link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something fancy
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, i knew i should have clarified. "this" is my activity that implements OnClickListener.

Comment: I'm using that very code on a TextView by the way.  Works perfectly.

Comment: was it a textview, and what version was it? I believe im targeting 2.1

Comment: My min is 3 and my target is 4 for complicated reasons.  LOL

Answer (score 2):

First click will be trap by focus event. You can simply intercept also onFocus:

```
final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            // Do something...
        }
    };
    link.setOnClickListener(listener);
    link.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(final View v, final boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
                listener.onClick(v);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try requesting focus for that view.

```
TextView link = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_area);
link.requestFocus();
link.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Register an onTouchListener instead of onClickListener - it should give you what you want.

Comment: what if they click on it with a mousetrack or something?

Comment: Register both?  Just make sure they don't both activate using a timed event or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

For Future Reference, I had a similar problem where the first click would change the color of the focusable TextView from a selector and the second click would fire my associated onClick function and I wanted one click to handle both. Using a global focus change listener solved this problem.I'm using the compatibility support v4 on android 2.3 with fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/yellow" />
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/darkgrey" />
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

Layout.xml...

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textColor="@drawable/textviewSelector"
    android:text="some text"/>
```

In my java file (Fragment) I have

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ViewTreeObserver VTO=getView().getViewTreeObserver();
        VTO.addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(new
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View oldFocus, View newFocus) {
                switch(newFocus.getId()){
                case R.id.tv1:
                //On click Code
                break;
                }
            }
        });
}
```